# getting the output of this php code

Tags: php

I want to get input from a form and save it to a php array and print the array.There is two files namely array.php and marks.php.I think I am messing with static.please help me!

**marks.php**

```
<style type="text/css">
.my_table{
margin-top:150px;
margin-left:400px;
}
</style>
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['send'])){
?>
<table  align='center' class='my_table'>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
<tr><th></th><th align='left'>Student Marks</th></tr>
<tr><td>enter subject</td><td><input type='text' name='subject'></td></tr>
<tr><td>enter marks</td><td><input type='text' name='marks'></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan='2' align='right'><input type='submit' value='submit' name='send'/>       </td></tr>
</form>
</table>
<?php
}
else{
    include 'array.php';
    $svtoarray=new SaveMarks();
$svtoarray->addToArray($_POST['marks']);
    $svtoarray->printArray();
    }
?>
```

**array.php**

```
<?php
class SaveMarks{
static $index=0;
function SaveMarks(){
    }
static $marks=array();
function addToArray($value){
    $marks[$index]=$value;
    $index++;
    }

function printArray(){
    $countarr=count($marks);
    for($ind=0;$ind<$countarr;$ind++){
        print $marks[ind];
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: $_POST is in itself an array. Why all the complicated stuff?

Comment: I think `<form><table></table></form>` is better than `<table><form></form></table>`. (Just a feeling :p)

Answer (score 0):

declaring a class member (method or property) means that the value is accessible directly from the class definition and does not have to be instantiated. Conversely, a static member cannot be accessed from an instantiation.
i.e.
becuase you declared index and marks as static

SaveMarks::$index or SaveMarks::$marks is okay

but
$svtoarray=new SaveMarks();
$svtoarray->index and $svttoarray->marks is not okay

See [PHP manual for static keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Instead of "static" you should declare them as "public" to be accessible from the instantiated object.
A more "pure" implementation would be to declare marks as private and define a public "setMarks" method rather than allow direct modification of a property.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = $_POST;
```

How does that look?